# how to execute a MySQL Query within an Asynchronous function within a node application

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, asynchronous

I am having some trouble using MySQL within a node/express JS application. It seems as though when trying to access the MySQL database within an asynchronous function, the code will 'skip over' the SQL and run synchronously. Here is my code; I am calling the getDeparturesForStop Method.

```
async function getDeparturesForStop(stop_id, route_type, con) {
    console.log("---Log before Asynch---");
    departures = await getDeparturesFromDatabase(con,stop_id);
    console.log("departures is : ");
    console.log(departures);
    console.log("---Log after Asynch---")
}
```

The getDeparturesFromDatabase method:

```
async function getDeparturesFromDatabase(con,stop_id){
    let myresult;
    con.query(`select * from departures WHERE stopID = ${stop_id} AND timestamp = '2020-04-08 13:48:00'`,function (err, result, fields){
        myresult = result[0];
        console.log("MyRes Inside sql query is :  ");
        console.log(result[0]);
    });
    return myresult;
}
```

The result I am expecting would be:

```
---Log before Asynch---
MyRes Inside sql query is :
//The result from the SQL  Query
departures is : 
//The result from the SQL Query
---Log after Asynch---
```

However, It would appear that the asynch function is getting called AFTER everything. The actual output is :

```
---Log before Asynch---
departures is :
undefined
---Log after Asynch---
MyRes Inside sql query is :
//The result from the SQL  Query
```

I am unsure If i am using these methods incorrectly. This will only happen when using a MySQL Query within the Async function. For example, If i were to assign a variable in the following fassion it would output as expected:

```
async function getDeparturesFromDatabase(con,stop_id){
let myresult = 5;
return myresult;
}
```

This will returrn the value Asynchronously as expected:

```
---Log before Asynch---
departures is : 
5
---Log after Asynch---
```

I am unsure if this is an issue with the MySQL Libary, or if this is an issue with the way I have developed the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` expects a Promise to work. you need to promisify the `query` method.

```
function getDeparturesFromDatabase(con,stop_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = `select * from departures WHERE stopID = ${stop_id} AND timestamp = '2020-04-08 13:48:00'`;
        con.query(query, function (err, result, fields){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(result[0]);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: This works as expected. - were you meant to add any additional comments when you said 'Note that'?

Comment: Opss... Edit it out. tnx